# Conversion of java to scala

Tags: scala

I have a working code in Java but I want to convert the same code in scala. So this is what my Java code is:

```
public class ScannerError extends RuntimeException {
  public ScannerError(String expected, Token look) {
    super(look.fileName + ":" + look.lineNumber + 
          " Expected: " + expected + 
          " Found: " + look);
  }
}
```

I converted the above code in scala as:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
object ScannerError(expected: String, look: Token) extends RuntimeException(look.fileName + ":" + look.lineNumber + " Expected: " + 
expected + " Found: " + look)
```

The scala code gives error at `expected:` Error message is "traits or objects may not have parameters".

Comment: `ScannerError` should be a class, not an object. Or a case class, even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` is the scala encoding of the singleton pattern and singletons don't take parameters by definition.
Use a `class` instead:

```
class ScannerError(expected: String, look: Token)
  extends RuntimeException(s"${look.fileName}: ${look.lineNumber} Expected: $expected Found: $look")
```